# Failure using geom_polygon with 2D facet_grid: 1D works

Tags: ggplot2, polygon, facet-grid, geom

I'm trying to add a state map boundary to a 2D facet_grid in ggplot which plots correlations against principal components (PC).

The 1D case works but I cannot discover what is causing the failure in the 2D case.  It may be a limit to facet_grid in some way or, more likely, something I don't understand.

```r
ggplot(A0G, aes(Longitude, Latitude, color=Correlation)) +
 + geom_point(size=2*abs(A0G$Correlation)) +     
 + geom_polygon(data = ca_df, aes(x=Longitude, y=Latitude, fill = NA, color = "black")) +
 + facet_grid(rows=vars(A0G$Lag), cols=vars(A0G$PC))  
    
# Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "PANEL", value = c(4L, 3L, 5L,  10L,  :
# replacement has 11112 rows, data has 516
```

The issue seems related to the dimensions of the map df and the data df but I can't grok the problem since it works in the 1D case.

> dim(ca_df)
> [1] 516   6

> dim(A0G)
> [1] 11112    18

Any suggestions welcome.  I'll just keep breaking the problem down if there isn't anything obvious.

Comment: Have you tried `rows=vars(Lag), cols=vars(PC)` instead?

Comment: That helped.  Then it complained about discrete versus continuous color.  I move the fill and color for the map outside of the aes and that seemed to be key as well as your suggestion.